# How to tell if you're compiling on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Something like:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
// do stuff
#endif
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  The answer will probably depend on the compiler.

Comment: Visual Studio on windows, GCC on linux

Comment: Compiling *on* Windows, or compiling *for* Windows?

Comment: Is there a sweaty homunculus yelling "DEVELOPERS! DEVELOPERS! DEVELOPERS!" in your ear?  Then you're compiling on Windows.

Comment: Wow, you get a free Ballmer with every copy of Windows 7 these days? MS really are desperate for it to outsell Vista / no wonder XP is still more popular [delete as applicable].

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The _WIN32 is always defined on Windows platform, checkout the [predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Comment: It is defined only if you include a certain file in your project, or using Visual Studio.

Comment: Although I seem to remember having a bit of a surprise once that the compiler for the Symbian emulator defined either _WIN32 or something like it. Sort of made sense, the emulator does run on Windows after all, but we didn't actually want our Win32-specific clauses to apply...

Comment: The _WIN32 macro is defined by the Microsoft C Compiler (cl.exe), it requires no additional #includes.

Answer (score 7):

This is the most complete table I know of.
https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what files are you using.

The compiler itself doesn't have such a flag, but it is common to have such a define in the operating system's SDK.

For example, the CRT has a Win32 define, which affects how it is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question but yes, you can do this.  Obviously, you need to tell the compiler you're compiling on Windows (or operating system x) at compile time.  I've seen a similar approach used for bit size of things like integers.